# style ul part in custom menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to style **ul** part of navigation menu(custom menu) in **wordpress**? I have tried

```
<div id="serviceMenu">
  <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'navigation with more options',
  'container' => '',
  'menu_id'  => '',
  'menu_class' => 'menu')); ?>
  </div>
```

But I don't know how to assign `class="menu"` to **ul** part?

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the manual of  wp_nav_menu I would suggest the following code for adding an menu class to the ul:

```
<div id="serviceMenu">
<?php 
  wp_nav_menu(array(
  'menu'=>'navigation with more options',
  'container' => '',
  'menu_id'  => '',
  'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  'menu_class' => 'menu')); 
?>
</div>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu